# Cannot get data of logged in User in Django

Tags: python, django, api, rest, backend

Respect for everyone here.
I have `CustomUser model` from one app, and `Field` model from another app. And I put a connection in `CustomUser model` with `Field` model via `ManyToMany`.

> *Field is for interested fields, and in signup form I have input like "In What do you have interests?"*

I can easily get other datas like username, date_of_birth, email... But cannot get this `interests`. It returns `courses.Field.None`

**Here is the models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from courses.models import Field

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32 , verbose_name="Login", unique=True, )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name="Ismingiz", blank=False, null=False)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name="Familyangiz", blank=False, null=False)
    # & dob = date of birth
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Yoshingiz", blank=False, null=True)
    gender_choices = [("e", "Erkak"), ("a", "Ayol")]
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices, verbose_name="Jinsingiz", default="e", max_length=1)
->  interests = models.ManyToManyField(Field, verbose_name="Qiziqishlaringiz")
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Yashash joyingiz (uzunlik)", null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Yashash joyingiz (kenglik)", null=True, blank=True)
```

And this is my views.py file from `courses` App

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Center
from .serializers import CenterSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.response import Response
from decimal import Decimal
from slugify import slugify
import operator
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
...
other views here
...
def center_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        dorilar = Center.objects.all()
        serializers = CenterSerializer(dorilar, many=True)
        dorixonalar = []
        uzunlik = request.GET.get('uz')
        kenglik = request.GET.get('keng')
------> print(request.user.interests)
        interests = request.GET.get('interest').split(",")
        if uzunlik and kenglik:
            uzunlik = Decimal(uzunlik)
            kenglik = Decimal(kenglik)
            location = Decimal(uzunlik + kenglik)
            dorixonalar = yaqinlik_boyicha_filter(dorilar, location, interests)
            serializers = CenterSerializer(dorixonalar, many=True)
            return Response(serializers.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializers.data)
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request.user.interests is a Manager. You need to:

```
print(request.user.interests.all())
```